# Problems With Error Casting In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Not sure if this a bug or an intended feature.

To create a user with an email and password in Firebase, I've been using the following code:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        guard let error = error as? FIRAuthErrorCode else { return } // ALWAYS FAILS 
        ...code...
    }
    ...code...
}
```

The error parameter in the completion handler for the method cannot be cast as `FIRAuthErrorCode`; it always fails. Is that a bug, or is that the expected behaviour?

Edit: I am aware that error codes can be used to distinguish between the different types of `FIRAuthErrorCode` errors. It's just not readable, and it doesn't make much sense for the error parameter in the completion handler to be not of be of type `FIRAuthErrorCode`. The cases and error codes of `FIRAuthErrorCode` can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/FIRAuthErrorCode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Firebase support about the issue, they've said that the errors that are passed back in completion handlers are just `Error` objects. They weren't `FIRAuthErrorCode` objects. To test for the various `FIRAuthErrorCode` cases, one would have to do something like this:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        guard let error = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) else {
            fatalError("This should never be executed")
        }
        switch error {
        case .errorCodeInvalidEmail: ...
        case .errorCodeWrongPassword: ...
        default: ...

        }
        ...code...
    }
    ...code...
}
```

^ This preserves readability and makes error handling more intuitive. And, there is no need for error casting!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `guard let error = error as! FIRAuthErrorCode else { return }` to force the casting and check whether the return is nil or not?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to compile doing that because it would result in a conditional binding error. Forcing a downcast using `as!` always returns a non-optional value, so it doesn't make sense to use `guard let`. But I did test out `let error = error as! FIRAuthErrorCode` before, and it produced the following error: `Could not cast value of type 'NSError' (0x1149070b8) to '__C.FIRAuthErrorCode' (0x104e35718).`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation of signIn method in firebase in order to check the all possible type of error this method can send and then check those type of errors in guard block in your code.

Comment: I've already done that but it requires the use of error codes (raw values of the various cases in `FIRAuthErrorCode`). I would prefer to use the error code names instead (`FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse, FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeWrongPassword, etc...)`. One would think that casting from `error` to `FIRAuthErrorCode` would work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it's how I do my login and it seems to work great.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: EmailField.text!, password: PasswordField.text!, completion: { user, error in
        if error == nil {
        print("Successfully Logged IN \(user!)")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Login", sender: self)
        }
    })
```

I just check that there's not an error with the signin process, then perform my segue.

Comment: My existing code works well when there aren't any errors. I have no problems with that. It's the error handling that I am having trouble with. I am trying to deal with invalid passwords/emails/etc...